# Can I query MongoDB in reverse order?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a route that handles requests for posts by a certain user.  I want each request to serve the latest 25 posts matching the given author, and on the next request serve the 25 after that.  My code so far:

```
router.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
 Post.find({'author': req.params.id})
  .skip(req.query.skip)
  .limit(25)
  .populate({
    path: 'author',
    select: 'firstName lastName img'
  }).then(
    posts =>{
      res.json({posts: modifyPosts(posts, req.user._id)})
    }
  ).catch(
    err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.json({err: err})
    }
  )
})
```

I want to serve the newest posts first, and serve older documents to the client later. "req.query.skip" is incremented on the client side before each request. If I understand correctly, adding the .sort("date") method will still return the same 25 documents.  The code I have written always returns the oldest 25 documents first, so I guess am basically looking for an option that will let me search the database from the bottom up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the newest posts first you need to use `.sort({ date: -1 })` or `.sort('-date')` in mongoose query.

**UPDATED**

If you are using `.populate()`, sort should be inside populate.

```
.populate({
    path: 'author',
    select: 'firstName lastName img',
    options: { sort: { 'date': -1 }}
  }
```

Comment: That still returns the oldest documents.  I believe the sort method takes whichever documents are passed to it by .find() and sorts them, but does not alter the results of .find()

Comment: I'm still getting the same results

Comment: @AlexanderMiller Can you add Post schema in your question?

Comment: Embarrassing plot twist: I was debugging the wrong route.  Your first solution does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like below in GET request APIs:

```
db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }, function(err, docs){
            console.log(docs);
            res.json(docs);
        });
```

Hope this helps! Thanks.